# Unable to access web application running on a certain machine

Tags: java, windows, web-applications, jboss, jboss5.x

Tried deploying a simple web application (jboss 5.1, jboss seam 2.2.1) on a machine. But for some weird reason, I am unable to access the application using `http://localhost:8080/<my-app>`.

Any access to the application on a IE 8 browser, just gets re-directed to the search page with a string "localhost:8080".

Couple of observations:-

1. I tried switching off the firewall protection on the machine, but this didn't help
2. I tried switching off the Avast virus protection software process, but this didn't help.
3. Tried starting JBoss application server using run.bat -b 0.0.0.0 (didn't help)

Any ideas on what is happening here?

Comment: did you take a look at exception when deploying your war file?

Comment: the war file deployed just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the hosts file on that machine is not set correctly?  Try http://127.0.0.1:8080/ instead.

Comment: I tried it with localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.2 (from ipconfig) - none of them seemed to work

Comment: Is is possible something else is running on port 8080?  Have you checked jboss' startup logs?

Comment: I was looking at the console logs and everything looked normal to me.

Comment: You mentioned IE specifically, have you tried other browsers?  Also can you access the JMX console (http://localhost:8080/jmx-console) or one of the other built in JBoss administrative pages?

Comment: the machine didn't have other browsers, so I couldnt try it. Since the default page itself wasn't available, I didn't try the jmx-console

Answer (score 1):

You running on *nix? See if your web-server is running on this port. You can use `netstat -an` for this purpose.
Post your results, and then we can help you further.

Comment: well this is a stupid answer.. you have already mentioned you using anti-virus n all.. so your box has to be a windows. pls ignore.

Comment: jboss application server prints information saying that it started on port 8080. I didn't run netstat though

Comment: try pinging your machine on 8080 port. Also I would check if java process is still running or not..

Comment: java process is definitely running. How do you check if the process is running on port 8080 (one mechanism is via netstat -an). are there any other ways

Comment: Not sure about similar utilities for windows. (One option would be to install Cygwin to run Unix commands on your windows box. But there's gotta be smarter solutions than that.)

Comment: This is not a dev machine and I don't think will be able to install Cygwin. I can only rely on the tools which are provided by the OS.